# How to integrate hdf5 with visual studio code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, hdf5

I am doing a project on scientific computation in C and I produce a lot of data. I learned about how hdf5 can be a could format to save large amounts of data. I doing my coding on visual studio code. I have downloaded and installed the "hdf5-1.12.1-Std-win10_64-vs16" from the HDF5 website. I have tried including the lib folder from the hdf5 installation in the VSC include path. But I am getting the following error when I run a sample code with hdf5: "fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory". I am not very proficient with these installations of libraries and dependencies. What more should I do to get my code working?